# While extruding, The model connects itself to other faces

Tags: modeling, edges, unity, extrude, collision

I was trying to make a collider mesh for unity and just mapping out the map with knife tool then while cutting a building and extruding it when I clicked left clicked to confrim, it turned into second picture. Anyone knows how to deal with this?(btw magnet is not open)

[image: this is what is before extrusion]

[image: this is what it looks like after i confirm the extrusion(aka click left mouse)]

Comment: I think we'll need to see your Blend file. You can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the link to it and then edit your question and paste the link into it. Just the section which is giving you problems if it's a large file.

Comment: How small are you working? Have you got auto-merge vertices turned on? this looks vaguely like that kind of behaviour potentially

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Auto merge button location in 3d viewport]

At the top right of the 3d viewport, you'll see the button highlighted in blue in the image above. If it's lit, then "Auto Merge" is enabled.

Under "Active Tool and Workspace Settings" (in the Properties panel, located by clicking the top left icon in any window, the button is on the right-most column, second from the top) you can find Auto Merge under the Options panel.

Expand that and you'll be able to change the Threshold. It's possible your scene is too small and the threshold is merging vertices.

Otherwise, be sure to check for Modifiers which may be deforming the geometry.

Comment: yep that seem to work, thanks for the help!